# SignalR works locally but doesn't work after deploy

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using SingnalR JavaScript Client at my .Net 5 application. (Windows Server 2016, IIS 10)

Locally is working fine. On browser console, I can see the transporte method as

*WebSocket connected to wws://localhost:44300/PedidoHub?id=...*

But, after deploy to IIS, doesn't work corretly anymore, works once in a while. On browser, hather than WebSocket, I can see transport method as

*SSE Connected to https://mydomain/PedidoHub?id=...*

Update:

After WebSocket Protocol installed on server, I can see transport method as locally, that is, *WebSocket connected to wws://localhost:44300/PedidoHub?id=...*

But still not working. Every change on my dashboard works fine sending to the client, but the opposite doesn't work.

My Hub class is:

```
public class PedidoHub : Hub
{
    // ** This method work fine after deploy (on Server)
    public async Task AtualizaTrakerCliente(int status)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("GetStatusPedido", status);
    }

    // ** This method looks like doesnt work after deploy (on Server)
    public async Task AtualizaDashBoad(int idPedido)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("NovoPedido", idPedido);
    }
}
```

1º JavaScript code (dashboard):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/pedidoHub")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

    connection.start()
        .then(function () {
            // ** This connection looks like doesnt work after deploy (on Server)
            connection.on('NovoPedido', function (idPedido) {
                if (idPedido > 0) {
                    atualizaPedidos();
                }
            });
        });

    atualizaPedidos = function () {
        var options = {};
        options.type = "POST";
        options.url = "/api/IconsMenuTopCountPos";
        options.cache = true;
        options.async = true;
        options.dataType = "JSON";
        contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            options.data = {
                "id": 1,
                "view1": "_PosIconPedidoCountPartial",
                "view2": "_PosIconEntregasCountPartial",
                "view3": "_PosIconCaixaMsgCountPartial"
            };

        options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        };

        options.success = function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $('#IconPedidosCount').html(data.partialViewConfirmar);
                $('#IconEntregasCount').html(data.partialViewEnteguar);
                $('#IconCaixaMsgCount').html(data.partialViewCaixa);

                const audio = new Audio("https://freesound.org/data/previews/377/377639_7003434-lq.mp3");
                audio.onended = function () {
                   
                    if (window.location.pathname == '/Pos/Pedido/Producao' || window.location.pathname == '/Pos/Pedido/Entregas') {
                        if ($('#Modal').is(':hidden')) {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                }
                audio.play();
            }
        };

        options.error = function () {
            alertify.error('Erro: atualiza novo pedido');
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    };
})
```

2º JavaScript code (client):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/pedidoHub")
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .build();

        connection.start()
            .then(function () {
                // ** This one works fine! After deploy (on Server)
                connection.on('GetStatusPedido', function (status) {
                    if (status > 0) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
    })
```

3º JavaScript code (client):

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnPagar").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _this = $(this);
        var _form = _this.closest("form");

        var isvalid = _form.valid();

        if (isvalid) {
            checkOut();
        }
        else {
            //alert('false');
        }
    });

    checkOut = function () {
        var options = {};
         
        options.type = "POST";
        options.url = "/api/CheckOut";
        options.dataType = "JSON";
        options.cache = true;
        options.async = true;
        contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        options.data = $('#formCheckout').serialize(); 

        options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                $('#itemLoader').modal('toggle');
                $('#itemLoader').modal('show');
        };
        
        options.success = function (data) {
            if (data.success)
            {
                if (data.idPedido != null) {
                    connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                        .withUrl("/pedidoHub")
                        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
                        .withAutomaticReconnect()
                        .build();

                    connection.start()
                        .then(function () {
                        // ** This Connection/invoke looks like doesnt work after deploy (on Server)
                            connection.invoke("AtualizaDashBoad", data.idPedido);
                        });

                    window.location.href = "/app/pedido/pedido?idPedido=" + data.idPedido;
                }
            }
            else
            {
               //omitted for brevity
            }
        };

        options.error = function (res) {
            $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
            $('#itemLoader').modal('dispose');
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    };
});
```

My c# method (dashboard):

```
    private async Task EnviarMsgHubTracker(int status)
    {
           HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://mydomain/pedidoHub")
            .Build();
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        // ** This works fine from C# Controller. After deploy (on Server)
        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("AtualizaTrakerCliente", status);
        await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
```

At my Startup.cs

```
              services.AddSignalR();
              services.AddCors(options =>
              {
                  options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                  {
                      builder.WithOrigins("https://mydomain")
                        .AllowCredentials();
                  });
              });

             //omitted for brevity

            app.UseCors();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                //omitted for brevity

                endpoints.MapHub<PedidoHub>("/pedidoHub");
                    
            });
```

Comment: please describe your code

Comment: Supported Platforms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms (IIS 8 or IIS 8 Express)

Comment: Does the IIS you're deploying to support web sockets and have it turned on? Sounds like signalr is falling back to long polling or repeat requesting..

Comment: Probably also worth noting that lack of evidence of a WSS connection isn't evidence of SignalR not working; it's designed to fall back from web sockets, to long polling (a normal http connection that remains open for long, with no data passing, and then re-establishes again if closed) or one of its brethren

Comment: Could you please tell me which server you have hosted your web application on windows 10 or server 2012? And is there have any error message?

Comment: I'm using IIS 10 on Windows Server 2012. I have just installed the WebSocket Protocol (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support). Now, instead of "SSE Connected to https" I have the same as locally,  that is, I have "WebSocket connected to wws:". I was expecting it worked. Every change on my dashboard works fine sending to the client, but the opposite doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at Event Viewer, but nothing wrong happens. @ZhiLv

Comment: A correction. I'm using windows server 2016 @ZhiLv